# Explanation of the experiment with Mach–Zehnder interferometer (self-interference of a single photon)

Tags: quantum-optics, interferometry

Here is the description of experiment which uses Mach–Zehnder interferometer

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%E2%80%93Zehnder_interferometer

or

http://departments.colgate.edu/physics/research/Photon/root/ajpbs02.pdf

(see section "C. The experiments: The photon interferes with itself")

However I don't think I can fully understand the nature of what's happening in this experiment

Could possibly someone give an explanation preferably in simple terms or point to another source?

Comment: I don't know too much about this experiment, but suffice to say that trying to understand this phenomenon intuitively will probably drive anyone insane!

Comment: It is not intuitive, at least not to me, so I agree. However I hope that there is a logical explanation, even the one which is not immediately graspable.

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: I complete Piotr's question : I see several possible points. Does the the problem with classical Mach-Zehnder interferometers ? Or in the fact that the classical interference apply also to single photons ?

Answer (score 4):

A very nice explanation [here](http://www.upscale.utoronto.ca/PVB/Harrison/MachZehnder/MachZehnder.html).

Don't forget:

> When a light ray is incident on a surface and the material on the other side of the surface has a higher index of refraction... then the reflected light ray is shifted in its phase by exactly one half a wavelength.

Comment: +1 good link. I think it would be even better if you summarize the argument of the linked page in your answer.

Comment: Uhm, I deliberately didn't want to do that because the info on the link is already summarized. If Art finds that explanation hard to understand, we can answer what he doesn't understand. By the way, according to http://iopscience.iop.org/0031-9120/35/1/308, there are a lot of references explaining the experiment that are 'grossly misleading'. So better to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

These comments relate to relatively simple examples of an evolving 
EM field, e.g., a single-photon field evolving through a Mach-Zehnder 
interferometer. Evolution of the field may be treated classically; there 
is no difference between classical and quantum evolution of the field, 
in this situation. But, discrete interactions, e.g., detections and emissions,
require quantum description. It took quantum devices to create the one-
quantum field; classical perspective is sufficient to describe its evolution 
through the interferometer. Detections are another matter.

The statement that the lack of two detections, with a single-photon field 
in the double-slit experiment, provides evidence for discrete photons is 
nonsense(!) Without "down-conversion" of the 1-photon field into two 
half energy photon fields, conservation of energy allows only one 
detection. The expectation of more is a ubiquitous misunderstanding in 
the "common lore"(!).

(Einstein would agree with this.)

Jim Johnston